ExcelJS RichText weird behaviour
I'm working on a Node.js project to parse an Excel file. My goal is to retrieve all cells where the text is in bold or italic. However, I'm encountering a strange issue.
Here’s what my Excel file looks like:


When I print a row, I get the following output:
[
  ...
  'Farge',
  ...
  'Répression',
  'I.214',
  { richText: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] }
]

I don't understand why the "DC" cell contains a RichText object, but the "BD" cell does not :(
Here is my code:
export default async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
  let file = (req.files as Express.Multer.File[])[0];

  excel.save();

  await workbook.xlsx.load(req.files[0].buffer);
  const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);  
  
  // ...  
  
  worksheet?.eachRow(async (row, rowIndex) => {
    try {
      console.log(row.values);      // <= Here
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(`Error with deporte index ${rowIndex}`);
      }
  });
  // ...
};

Can someone explain why this happens?
Thanks!
